# Old webcam reboots new PC

Tags: webcam

I have an old 3com webcam that might be 6 or 7 years old. A few months ago when I built muy new pc I found that if the webcam is connected the computer crashes. I realised that there was an incompatibility between the webcam and the motherboard or at least I thought so. As the webcam is really old I didn't care, it worked fine for years and that's what I needed.

My question is if anybody knows why this happens and if there's any way to fix it.
The computer freezes and reboots itself and then it doesn't boot at all if I connect the webcam with the pc on. If I connect it with the pc off then it just doesn't boot.

Comment: Do you have the latest drivers for it?

Comment: Yes I do but it reboots before I can install them.

Comment: I had the exact same thing happen with an old scanner (I'm assuming your camera is USB as well). The only thing that resolved it was to connect a USB 1.1 hub to my computer and attach the scanner to it. You could try that to see if it helps.

Comment: OS? webcam model?

Comment: What happens if you install the drivers before plugging in the webcam?

Comment: OS - Winsows XP // Webcam model - 3Com Home Connect 3cp5098

Comment: While installing drivers it asks for the webcam to be connected and it also crashes

Comment: The USB 1.1 could be the solution but I had tried it in a USB 2 port and it worked. So it doesn't just happen in every USB 2 port, it happens in mine.

Comment: Could be a USB controller issue, then. Just because there are specs doesn't mean that every manufacturer follows them completely or correctly....

Answer (score 1):

In comments you said you have the drivers yet they aren't installed yet. Try booting into safe mode and remove old drivers, then install the new ones.

Alternatively, a [USB hub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't boot at all it sounds like there may be a short in the webcam connector.  Does it work on another PC?

Comment: yes it does work on other PCs. Older PCs